# Erro ao criar as tabelas simultaneamente no banco sqlite

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile que salva os dados de um formulário no banco local, usando o `sqlite`. Só que toda vez que o banco é zerado ou mudo sua versão ele me retorna um erro que não foi possível criar as tabelas. Essas tabelas tem um relacionamento **One To Many**.

Curioso que se eu criar primeiro uma tabela, comentando a linha que cria a segunda tabela, e depois descomentar a mesma ele gera as duas normalmente. Como fazer pra não ter mais este erro, sendo que nos fóruns que vi, é dessa maneira que se cria as tabelas com `sqlite`.

Criando as tabelas:

```
public Conexao(Context context) {
    super(context, name, null, version);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table paciente(_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome varchar(50), cpf varchar(11), data varchar(15) )");
    db.execSQL("create table imagens(_id integer primary key autoincrement, status varchar(10), imagem varchar(300), FOREIGN KEY(paciente_id) REFERENCES paciente(_id))");
    Log.i("TAG", "Banco criado com sucesso");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("drop table paciente");
    db.execSQL("drop table imagens");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Inserindo novo cadastro:

```
public long inserirFoto(Foto imagem){

    List<String> fotos = imagem.getImagem();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for(int i = 0; i < fotos.size(); i++) {

        values.put("status", "skdoasm");
        values.put("imagem", "skfmsakf");

    }return banco.insert("imagens", null, values);
}

public long inserirPaciente(Paciente paciente){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("nome", paciente.getNome());
    values.put("cpf", paciente.getCpf());
    values.put("data", paciente.getData());
    return banco.insert("paciente", null, values);
}
```

Relacionamento tabelas:

```
public class Paciente implements Serializable {

private int id;
private String nome;
private String cpf;
public  Foto foto;
private String data;
getter e setter...

public class Foto  implements Serializable {

@Expose
private List<String> imagem;
@Expose
private int id;
@Expose
private String status;

public List<String> getImagem() {
    return imagem;
}

getter e setter...
```

Erro na saída:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown column "paciente_id" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: create table imagens(_id integer primary key autoincrement, status varchar(10), imagem varchar(300), FOREIGN KEY(paciente_id) REFERENCES paciente(_id))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, sua segunda tabela esta com script errado, veja:

```
create table imagens(
  _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
  status varchar(10), 
  imagem varchar(300), 
  FOREIGN KEY(paciente_id) REFERENCES paciente(_id)
)
```

Você diz que que `paciente_id` é sua chave estrangeira com referência na tabela `pacientes` coluna `_id`. Mas não tem nenhum `paciente_id` na declaração da sua tabela.
Altere para:

```
create table imagens(
  _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
  paciente_id integer NOT NULL,
  status varchar(10), 
  imagem varchar(300), 
  FOREIGN KEY(paciente_id) REFERENCES paciente(_id)
)
```

Ficando assim:

```
db.execSQL("create table imagens(_id integer primary key autoincrement, paciente_id integer NOT NULL, status varchar(10), imagem varchar(300), FOREIGN KEY(paciente_id) REFERENCES paciente(_id))");
```

Comment: Fiz as alteraçoes agora ta me retornando `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: imagens.paciente_id (code 1299)`

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet esse erro provavelmente deve estar aparecendo quando você faz um insert certo? Da uma olhada no seu insert pois nele não deve estar sendo informado o valor para o campo paciente_id!

Comment: no meu caso, que o paciente tem um relacionamento com foto e foto tem um arraylist de string(caminho dessas fotos) no SQL fica assim mesmo: imagem varchar(300)

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet só uma observação, se essa tabela pode armazenar valores null para o campo paciente_id, então altere o comando creat que passei e remova o NOT NULL de pacient_id, depois crie a tabela novamente para resolver esse erro

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet exatamente pelo fato de paciente ter relacionamento com a tabela imagens que você precisa inserir o id de paciente nela conforme estou te falando, se não como você pode mostrar qual imagem é de qual paciente? Poste o deu insert que lhe ajudo

Comment: deu certo, Murilo, obrigado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97907/discussion-between-tecnologia-da-net-and-murilo-portugal).